# get value / dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this data and i need access to the value low, high etc but i don't find a way to do it

im trying this:

data['1. open']

but says keyerror

i can acces to:
data['Meta Data'], Time Series (1min)

inclusive i can access to the values low, high.. using the date but the problem is that the date changes so..

hope you guys can help me, thanks!

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "",
        "2. Digital Currency Code": "",
        "3. Digital Currency Name": "",
        "4. Market Code": "",
        "5. Market Name": "",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "",
        "7. Interval": "",
        "8. Output Size": "",
        "9. Time Zone": ""
    },
    "Time Series (1min)": {
        "2021-12-30 03:45:00": {
            "1. open": "",
            "2. high": "",
            "3. low": "",
            "4. close": "",
            "5. volume": 8
        },
        "2021-12-30 03:44:00": {
            "1. open": "",
            "2. high": "",
            "3. low": "",
            "4. close": "",
            "5. volume":
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems pointless to have those ordinal numbers in the data.  Why "1. open" instead of just "open"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `"1. open"` is nested several levels deep.  You would have to use `data["Time Series (1min)"]["2021-12-30 03:45:00"]["1. open"]`.

To USE this data, you would iterate through the subkeys, as in

```
for k,v in data["Time Series (1min)"].items():
    prin( k, v["1. open"])
```

Comment: thisss, thx:) im so noob

Comment: Sometimes things aren't obvious until someone else points them out.